# Django dynamic URL tree

Tags: python, django

I'm new in Django and can't find a solution for my problem. 
How to make a dynamic URL tree in Django like - site.com/{categoryName}/{itemName}/

Now I have this URL tree:

site.com/item/{itemSlug}/

site.com/category/{itemCategorySlug}/

But I need:

site.com/{itemCategorySlug}/{itemSlug}/

How can I crate this URL tree without installing 3rd party plugins?

**Models**

```
from django.db import models
from django.shortcuts import reverse
from services.slug.generator import generate_slug



class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=400, unique=True)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=1000, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=500, unique=True, blank=True)
    seo_title = models.CharField(max_length=180, unique=True)
    seo_description = models.TextField(max_length=280, unique=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'category'
        verbose_name_plural = 'categories'

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('progress_category_url', kwargs={'slug': self.slug})

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.id:
            self.slug = generate_slug(self.name)
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name



class Progress(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=400, unique=True)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=1000, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=500, unique=True, blank=True)
    seo_title = models.CharField(max_length=180, unique=True)
    seo_description = models.TextField(max_length=280, unique=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_verified = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    profile = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    promo_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='progress/promo_images/', null=True, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'progress'
        verbose_name_plural = 'progresses'

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('progress_url', kwargs={'slug': self.slug})

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.id:
            self.slug = generate_slug(self.name)
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

**Views**

```
from django.views.generic.list import ListView
from django.views.generic.detail import DetailView
from .models import Progress, Category


class ProgressView(DetailView):
    model = Progress
    template_name = 'progresses/detail_tpl.html'


class CategoryView(ListView):
    model = Category
    template_name = 'progresses/list_tpl.html'
```

**URLs**

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import ProgressView, CategoryView


urlpatterns = [
    path('progress/<slug:slug>/', ProgressView.as_view(), name='progress_url'),
    path('category/<slug:slug>/', CategoryView.as_view(), name='progress_category_url'),
]
```

So in my case I need to create something like that:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('<slug:category_slug>/<slug:progress_slug>/', ProgressView.as_view(), name='progress_url'),
]
```

How can I do this?